# Can't use sudo apt-get update

Tags: debian, apt

I'm on Debian 11 and I have a lot of problems with commands these times but the strangest is that I can't update any more, when I try I get this :

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo/dists/core/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu kinetic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 957D2708A03A4626
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu kinetic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I hope someone knows how to help me cause I can't do anything without updating, Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

You're using Debian so you should not be trying to [update from Ubuntu repositories](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). Remove those from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and just use [the ones from Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Hi, your answer must be helpful but I just have a question for you, How can I do this ?(Im not really good with linux but you may have understood this ahah)